# Formula derivation related to binomial Conditional Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Per image below, how does A transform into B?
I'm referring to specifically, how Px,y(x,z-x) turns into px(x)py(z-x)
Thanks a lot for looking over my newbie question!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement is *incomplete*. The problem should have specified as an assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**.  For independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, we have 
$$\Pr((X,Y)=(a,b))=\Pr(X=a)\Pr(Y=b).$$ 
That is what is being used to get from A to B.